# Constraints on type parameters - where T: class

Tags: c#, generics, constraints

I have problem with constraints, because I want, that the type argument is a reference type just one of 3 classes, not the any others, so constraint "where L: class" is not ok.

Here is example:

```
public class MyClass <L> 
        where L : Circle
        where L: Rectangle
        where L: Triangle
```

This mean, that must comply with all constraints. Unfortunately, I have not found the answer yet.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do those 3 classes (`Circle`, `Rectangle`, `Triangle`) share a common ancestor?

Comment: Are you sure you want the class to comply with *all* constraints, instead of any? In other words, are you sure you want the class to derive from all three `Circle`, `Rectangle` and `Triangle`?

Comment: What you are describing is a union type, and C# does not support these, and OO does not really lend itself to closed hierarchies. You could use F# instead, or if you control all the code then define a base class/interface and add three extending types `Circle`, `Rectangle` and `Triangle`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should create a base class or interface that `Circle`, `Rectangle`, and `Triangle` inherit from.

For example:

```
interface IShape
{
}

class Circle : IShape
{
    // ...
}

class Rectangle : IShape
{
    // ...
}

class Triangle : IShape
{
    // ...
}
```

Then do the constraint on `IShape`:

```
public class MyClass <L> 
    where L : IShape
```

Comment: To add on to this: in case the source for `Circle`, `Rectangle` and/or `Triangle` isn't accessible, you can still inherit those types and implement the interface in your derived types, provided they aren't sealed

Comment: Probably those three shapes share common code, like coordinates or colors. These common things definitively belong in an abstract base class. (This base class can still implement the interface.)